# GD Library Image to Text Extended to include HTML?

Tags: php

I have the follwing code:

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];

if(!empty($Email)) {

echo"<img src=\"generatePic.php?em=" . $email . " />";

}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="get" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>Your E-mail</td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Imagefy Me!" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When I submit a string, however, the image returned contains the string, but also part of `<form action="...` as part of the string printed to the picture... Any suggestions on how I could avoid this?

Comment: Do you mean that’s in the output of the page containing the picture and it shouldn’t be, or that it’s in the content of the image itself? If it’s the latter, what does `generatePic.php` contain?

Comment: Do you know what ` />` means exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Email has `@` inside it, so you need ***[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)*** it, and you missed the quote.

```
echo"<img src=\"generatePic.php?em=" . urlencode($email) . "\" />";
```

Comment: What I basically get printed on the image is email@example.com /><form action=

Comment: @DarioPanada You missed the quote.